# Port forwarding From PC to Mikrotik To UBNT

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm having a Point To Point Device for reaching to internet. this device has valid IP address, ,and then it somehow connect to a Mikrotik router, and after that passing switches, will attach to another PC. As the ISP technesian requested i put the PPPoE on radio device, and keep it from bridging.
so currently two router are serving the path to the PC.

now, how to forward port from PC to Mikrotik Router, and Then To UBNT Device? i follow two seperate tutorial for mikrotik and ubnt, and open a port, then tried to test it with PFPortChecker, but it said the port is close. i let firewall to allow the software too.

Please can you provide images? too, (showing the network)?

I wanted to open Remote Desktop Port, But since i couldn't test it, i also use the port you see.

[image: MikroTik Port Forwarding]
[image: UBNT Port Forwarding]
[image: Results]

Comment: Two routers = Double NAT = Unlikely to work. You need to simplify your setup if you want this to work.

Comment: well for today i can, but soon i wont, and i want to try it before fall for it